# Storing Large documents in RavenDB causes client to go out of memory

Tags: object, out-of-memory, ravendb

We are trying to use RavenDB to store an object that when serialized to JSON is about 800K.

Storing 1 object takes about 100 ms in the RavenDB server and we are batching them and storing 10 at a time generating a new object every 100ms.

Eventually we run out of memory on the client as we see the server is not able to store them fast enough.

Is this a known problem, if so any way to optimize this?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered something similar. Disabling profiling via:

```
store.Conventions.DisableProfiling = true;
```

store being your DocumentStore

Worked for me when I ran out of memory once.

I would also advise to look at (and search) the RavenDB mailing list. It has really helped me get answers and many times my questions have already been answered. See http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/

Comment: You could also try to disable Raven’s Client Cache.  
Yet, you should do some memory profiling to find out what is actually exhausting the memory.